# I can't install rails on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

Whenever I run

```
    sudo gem install rails
```

I get the following output:

```
   ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

RVM version: rvm 1.18.14
and Ruby is 2.0.0p0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

So First I removed everything to do with RVM as suggested in some of the answers. Rebooted. Installed the latest Version of Xcode and the command line tools from Xcode (Xcode-prefereces-downloads). Then rebooted again, and finally used RailsInstaller. Once I used that rails was back on and all is good in the world. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 8):

you need to reinstall your rubies:

```
rvm get head --autolibs=3
rvm pkg remove
rvm reinstall all --force
```

the new `autolibs` supporrt will take care of updating dependencies and including them in ruby

Comment: when I try to reinstall:

`Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/moza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/libxslt:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/moza/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.`

Comment: you might be hitting another issue, make sure to run: `rvm get head` and read all the outputs, then install with `rvm reinstall ruby--autolibs=3`

Answer (score 4):

Do you have Homebrew installed on your system? If so, try

```
brew install openssl
```

in the command line.

Comment: Adding to this, you would need to re-install Ruby again afterwards or recompile the openssl extension

Comment: I tried that already:

    `brew install openssl
    Warning: Your Xcode (4.5.1) is outdated
    Please install Xcode 4.6.
    Error: openssl-1.0.1e already installe`

Comment: brew worked after update but on rails install this is the error that I get: `/Users/moza/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/moza/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long/Users/moza/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /Users/moza/.rvm/bin/gem: Undefined error: `

Answer (score 3):

hmm, you have rvm but why you need sudo?I thought rvm is in sandbox mode . Anyway, the error just means it can't find ssl path. First, make sure you have openssl installed. If not then you need to install it(brew, macport etc) or `rvm pkg install openssl` and let rvm manage its path(you have rvm already). After that, you will need to reinstall ruby. RVM guide is [here](https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use sudo. sudo is ONLY used for doing a multi-user install, and only then during the initial installation, and adding your user to the rvm group (if the installer did not do it for you which usually indicates you did the install wrong in the first place)